# Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000: One side button far softer than other

Tags: mouse, mouse-buttons

On a [Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-mouse-5000/MGC-00001) I just bought, the right side button (for next page) is far softer than the left side button (for last page).  Specifically, the right side button travels much farther than the left side button in order to click, making it unusually difficult to push.  Is this normal? or should the mouse be returned and replaced?

**Edit:**  The mouse button responds normally, and registers every time the button is fully depressed, but I'm not sure whether this would fail over time, and it is more difficult to press than it should be.  In any case, there is a three-year warranty on the mouse.

Comment: Sounds like a defect. I don't have that exact model but I have a similar one and the buttons are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the replacement mouse had the same behavior, and since another user reported the same problem, I will take it as an inherent design flaw.  The button works - it's just that it feels a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

A mouse with a soft button is indicative that the mouse suffered hard impact damage, like from dropping.

Sounds like the mouse package took a beating while in transit to the store. 
You should definitely seek a replacement.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll bring it back for replacement when I get a chance.